# JQuery - Stop accordion link from closing all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping someone can help me out with a problem i am having using the JQuery Accordion plugin. I have very little experience with JQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Basically, i have a link inside one of my accordion tabs which loads a new window. However, when this happens, it closes all of the accordion links within the parent window. I think it does this because it sees the link as part of the accordion which i do not want.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        // simple accordion
        /*jQuery('#accordion').accordion();*/
        jQuery('#accordion_click').accordion({
            /*animated: 'bounceslide'*/
            animated: 'easeslide',
            autoheight: true

        });

        jQuery('#accordion_hover').accordion({
            /*animated: 'bounceslide'*/
            event: 'mouseover',
            animated: 'bounceslide',
            autoheight: true

        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<a>Accordion Tab 1</a>
<div>
<a href="#" class="basic nonaccordion" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('www.newwindow.com','New_Window','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=200'); return false;">Load Window </a>
</div>

<a>Accordion Tab 2</a>
<div>
</div>

<a>Accordion Tab 3</a>
<div>
</div>

<a>Accordion Tab 4</a>
<div>   
</div>
```

Is there an easy way for me to remove the link within tab 1 from the accordion so that it does not close the tabs when the new window loads?

Thanks!

Edit: the CSS for this is below:

```
/*tab, accordion*/
/*tab 1*/
ul.tabs { margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; list-style: none; height: 32px; border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8; border-left: 1px solid #c8c8c8; width: 100%; }
ul.tabs li { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 31px; line-height: 31px; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;    border-left: none; margin-bottom: -1px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; background: #f5f5f5; }
ul.tabs li a { text-decoration: none; color: #9b9b9b; display: block; font-size:12px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; letter-spacing:3px; text-transform:uppercase; padding: 0 20px; border: 1px solid #fff; outline: none;}
ul.tabs li a:hover, ul.tabs li.active a { background: #fff; color:#000; }
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }
.tab_container { border: 1px solid #f5f5f5; border-top: none; overflow: hidden; clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; background: #fff; margin:0 0 20px 0; }
.tab_content { padding: 20px; }

/*tab 2*/
ul.tabs2 { margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; list-style: none; height: 32px; border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8; width: 100%; }
ul.tabs2 li { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 31px; line-height: 31px;  border-left: none; margin-bottom: -1px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
ul.tabs2 li a { text-decoration: none; color: #9b9b9b; display: block; font-size:12px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; letter-spacing:3px; text-transform:uppercase; padding: 0 20px; border: 1px solid #fff; outline: none;}
ul.tabs2 li a:hover, ul.tabs2 li.active a { background: #fff; color:#000; }
html ul.tabs2 li.active { background: #fff; border-top: 1px solid #c8c8c8; border-left: 1px solid #c8c8c8; border-right: 1px solid #c8c8c8;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }
html ul.tabs2 li.active a:hover{ color:#000; } 
.tab2_container { border: 1px solid #f5f5f5; border-top: none; overflow: hidden; clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; background: #fff; margin:0 0 20px 0; }
.tab2_content { padding: 20px; }

/*accordion*/
.basic  { width:100%; margin-bottom:40px;  }
.basic div {  background:none; }
.basic p { margin-bottom : 0px; border: none; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px;}
.basic a { cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:10px 10px; margin-top: 0; text-decoration: none; color: black; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; font-size:12px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; letter-spacing:3px; text-transform:uppercase; color: #9b9b9b;  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/collapsed.png) no-repeat 99% 50%; margin-bottom:1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;}
.basic a:hover { background-color:#fafafa; }
.basic a.selected { color: black; background: #fafafa url(../images/expanded.png) no-repeat 99% 50%;}
```

Comment: may we see more markup(including #accordion_hover and #accordion_click)?

Comment: Hi Dr Molle. I cannot find anything in the js file which refers to accordion_click or hover :S - The only other file i know has something to do with it is the CSS which i have added to the above - does this help? Thanks.

Comment: I mean the HTML-markup, there must be 2 elements with the IDs accordion_hover and accordion_click.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean! There is nothing with hover (im not sure this is being used) however the main div which has the accordion in it is using the click as follows: <div class="basic"  id="accordion_click">. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS you posted doesn't seem to be relevant to the HTML+JS.

Try using the `header` option and specifying the header to follow directly after the accordion element `> a`: http://jsfiddle.net/AkX3z/

I included the basic demo of `$.accordion` provided by the jQuery UI demos. It doesn't have this issue, which means it's probably due to your exclusion of a proper header.

Comment: Hi Royce Feng. Your solution worked perfectly for me and has helped me out greatly! Thank you, i really appreciate it! :)